# How to put Simple XML Serialization model-objects into a Bundle?

Tags: java, android, xml-serialization, parcelable

I am using the [Simple XML Serialization](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) library in my Android app for parsing and mapping an XML response from a web service to objects, like so:

```
@Root(name="root_tag", strict=false)
public class XMLRequest {

  @Path("a/b")
  @ElementList(name="routeList")
  private List<Route> routes;

  public ArrayList<Route> getRoutes() {
    return new ArrayList<Route>(routes);
  }
}
```

I have several more dependent model-classes (like `Route`) written in a similar way with the proper annotations, the parsing an mapping works fine.

I now want to pass the `Route` list to a new fragment and display it in a `ListView`. There are quite a lot of variables in several more model-classes, so I just wanted those classes to implement `Parcelable` and pass the list like this to my fragment:

```
public static ResultFragment newInstance(ArrayList<Route> routes) {
    ResultFragment fragment = new ResultFragment();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putParcelableArrayList(ROUTE_LIST_KEY, routes);
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    return fragment;
  }
```

My problem: I can't let the model-classes implement `Parcelable`, that breaks the mapping with the Simple framework. I also don't want to write new Parcelable model objects, that's redundant work which increases when I have to adjust my model classes. Putting every single variable in the bundle is also not an option, there are too many and also too many lists.

What I tried so far as a work-around is to pass the result string to the fragment (instead of the objects) and do the parsing and mapping there. But the process takes a while and I only want to do it once and just use my model objects from there on.

Does anyone have a suggestion how I can solve this? I would really like to keep the `Simple` mapping, because manual parsing and mapping via XMLPull would be a lot more work. Thanks!

Comment: If someone finds this: I ended up rewriting the parser using the recommended XMLPull and wrote my own (parcelable) model classes. It turned out that the Simple XML lib was slow (and big) anyway, so I can

Comment: .. cannot recommend using it for Android in the first place.